# Empty ADDRESS kubernetes ingress

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I tried configuring ingress on my kubernetes cluster. I followed the [documentation](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/#generic-deployment) to install ingress controller and ran the following commands

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/master/deploy/mandatory.yaml
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/master/deploy/provider/baremetal/service-nodeport.yaml
```

After that default-http-backend and nginx-ingress-controller were running:

```
ingress-nginx   default-http-backend-846b65fb5f-6kwvp      1/1       Running   0          23h       192.168.2.28   node1
ingress-nginx   nginx-ingress-controller-d658896cd-6m76j   1/1       Running   0          6m        192.168.2.31   node1
```

I tried testing ingress and I deployed the following service:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: echoserver-deploy
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: echo
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: echo
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: my-echo
          image: gcr.io/google_containers/echoserver:1.8
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: echoserver-svc
spec:
  selector:
    app: echo
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
```

And the following ingress:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: happy-ingress
  annotations:
    INGRESS.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
    - host: happy.k8s.io
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /echoserver
            backend:
              serviceName: echoserver-svc
              servicePort: 8080
```

When I ran the command 'kubectl get ing' I received:

```
NAME            HOSTS          ADDRESS   PORTS     AGE
happy-ingress   happy.k8s.io             80        14m
```

I didn't have ADDRESS resolved and I can’t figure out what the problem is because all the pods are running. Can you give me a hint as to what the issue can be?

Thanks

Comment: Any useful info in logs of `nginx-ingress-controller` pod?

Comment: Hello, , I found the issue. I was expecting the service to be exported on port 80, but it is exported on 30927. Can I configure this to be exported on port 80?

Comment: [https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/kubernetes-basics/expose/expose-intro/](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/kubernetes-basics/expose/expose-intro/)

Answer (score 60):

You have to enable `ingress addons` by following command before creating ingress rules. You can also enable it before executing any other command

```
$ minikube addons enable ingress
ingress was successfully enabled
```

Wait until the pods are up and running. You can check by executing following command and wait for the similar output

```
kubectl get pods -n kube-system | grep nginx-ingress-controller

nginx-ingress-controller-5984b97644-jjng2   1/1       Running   2          1h
```

[image]
For `Deployment` you have to specify the `containerPort` and for `Service` you have to specify `http` protocol.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: echoserver-deploy
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-echo
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-echo
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: my-echo
          image: gcr.io/kubernetes-e2e-test-images/echoserver:2.1
          ports:
          - containerPort: 8080
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: echoserver-svc
spec:
  selector:
    app: my-echo
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 8080
    name: http
```

For ingress rule change the port `servicePort` from 8080 to 80 the default http port.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: happy-ingress
  annotations:
    INGRESS.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - host: happy.k8s.io
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /echoserver
        backend:
          serviceName: echoserver-svc
          servicePort: 80
```

Now apply those files and create your pods, service and ingress rule. Wait few moment, it will take few moments to get ADDRESS for your ingress rule.
[image]
Now you can visit your service using `minikube ip` address but not by host name yet. For that you have to add the host and respective IP address in `/etc/hosts` file. So open `/etc/hosts` file in your favorite editor and add below line where  is the actual IP of you minikube

```
<minikube_ip> happy.k8s.io
```

Now you access you service using host name. Verify be following command

```
curl http://happy.k8s.io/echoserver
```

Answer (score 13):

As official [document](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/baremetal/#over-a-nodeport-service) say:

> Because NodePort Services do not get a LoadBalancerIP assigned by
>   definition, the NGINX Ingress controller does not update the status of
>   Ingress objects it manages

You have deployed the NGINX Ingress controller as described in the installation guide, so it is normal for your ADDRESS was empty!

Instead, the external client must append the NodePort allocated to the ingress-nginx Service to HTTP requests.

ps. This question is not about minikube

Comment: In this situation who is "external client"? Also, what do you mean by "append the NodePort allocated to the ingress-nginx Service to HTTP requests", what do you append to HTTP requests, and how do you append something to HTTP requests? Thanks!

Comment: external client: Any machine can only touch the node machine, but not the Pod network.
append the NodePort to HTTP request: `http://node.mydomain:nodeport`

Answer (score 12):

Ingress problems are specific to your implementation, so let me just speak to a bare-metal, LAN implementation with no load-balancer.

The key validation point of an ingress resource is that it gets an address (after all, what am I supposed to hit, if the ingress doesn't have an address associated with it?)  So if you do

```
kubectl get ingress some-ingress
```

Over and over (give it 30 seconds or so) and it never shows an address - what now?

On bare-metal LAN there are a few trouble spots.   First, ensure that your Ingress *resource* can find your Ingress *controller* - so (setting aside the controller spec for now) your resource needs to be able to find your controller with something like:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: web-api-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
```

Where your controller has entries like:

```
Labels:                   app.kubernetes.io/component=controller
                          app.kubernetes.io/instance=ingress-nginx
                          app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm
                          app.kubernetes.io/name=ingress-nginx
                          app.kubernetes.io/version=1.0.4
                          helm.sh/chart=ingress-nginx-4.0.6
```

But now let's go back a step - your controller - is it setup appropriately for your (in my case) bare-metal LAN implementation?   (this is all made super-easy by the cloud providers, so I'm providing this answer for my friends in the private cloud community)

There the issue is that you need this essential hostNetwork setting to be true, in your Ingress *controller* deployment.    So for that, instead of using the basic yamil (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/controller-v1.0.4/deploy/static/provider/baremetal/deploy.yaml) - wget it, and modify it to set the spec of the template of the spec of the Deployment, so that hostNetwork: true - something like (scroll down to the end):

```
# Source: ingress-nginx/templates/controller-deployment.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: ingress-nginx-4.0.6
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 1.0.4
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
  name: ingress-nginx-controller
  namespace: ingress-nginx
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
      app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  minReadySeconds: 0
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
        app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
        app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
    spec:
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      containers:
        - name: controller
          image: k8s.gcr.io/ingress-nginx/controller:v1.0.4@sha256:545cff00370f28363dad31e3b59a94ba377854d3a11f18988f5f9e56841ef9ef
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          lifecycle:
            preStop:
              exec:
                command:
                  - /wait-shutdown
          args:
            - /nginx-ingress-controller
            - --election-id=ingress-controller-leader
            - --controller-class=k8s.io/ingress-nginx
            - --configmap=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/ingress-nginx-controller
            - --validating-webhook=:8443
            - --validating-webhook-certificate=/usr/local/certificates/cert
            - --validating-webhook-key=/usr/local/certificates/key
          securityContext:
            capabilities:
              drop:
                - ALL
              add:
                - NET_BIND_SERVICE
            runAsUser: 101
            allowPrivilegeEscalation: true
          env:
            - name: POD_NAME
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: metadata.name
            - name: POD_NAMESPACE
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: metadata.namespace
            - name: LD_PRELOAD
              value: /usr/local/lib/libmimalloc.so
          livenessProbe:
            failureThreshold: 5
            httpGet:
              path: /healthz
              port: 10254
              scheme: HTTP
            initialDelaySeconds: 10
            periodSeconds: 10
            successThreshold: 1
            timeoutSeconds: 1
          readinessProbe:
            failureThreshold: 3
            httpGet:
              path: /healthz
              port: 10254
              scheme: HTTP
            initialDelaySeconds: 10
            periodSeconds: 10
            successThreshold: 1
            timeoutSeconds: 1
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 80
              protocol: TCP
            - name: https
              containerPort: 443
              protocol: TCP
            - name: webhook
              containerPort: 8443
              protocol: TCP
          volumeMounts:
            - name: webhook-cert
              mountPath: /usr/local/certificates/
              readOnly: true
          resources:
            requests:
              cpu: 100m
              memory: 90Mi
      nodeSelector:
        kubernetes.io/os: linux
      serviceAccountName: ingress-nginx
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 300
      hostNetwork: true
      volumes:
        - name: webhook-cert
          secret:
            secretName: ingress-nginx-admission
```

Deploy that, then setup your ingress *resource*, as indicated above.

Your key tests are:

- Does my ingress have a dedicated node in my bare-metal implementation?
- if I hit port 80 on the ingress node, do I get the same thing as hitting the NodePort?    (let's say NodePort is 31207 - do I get the same thing hitting port 80 on the ingress node as hitting port 31207 on any node?)

Final note: Ingress has changed a lot over the past few years, and tutorials are often providing examples that don't pass validation - please feel free to comment on this answer if it has become out of date

Comment: Thanks adding `kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx` annotation solved my problem.

Comment: `kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx` is the recipe!

Comment: i tried this my ingress still has no address

Answer (score 5):

Your `hostname happy.k8s.io` should resolve to an actual IP address of the nginx-ingress-controller, which points to the front of your load balancer.

You can check under which IP is the cluster working:

```
bash-3.2$ kubectl cluster-info
Kubernetes master is running at https://192.168.1.100:8443
KubeDNS is running at https://192.168.1.100:8443/api/v1/namespaces/kube- 
system/services/kube-dns:dns/proxy
```

Test the ingress controller for your cluster using `curl`

```
bash-3.2$ curl http://192.168.1.100:8080
default backend - 404
```

In the end, you should just add the domain entry to `/etc/hosts` :

```
192.168.1.100   happy.k8s.io
```

Answer (score 5):

I don't know if this will help, but i had the same problem.
I didn't install no ingress controller or whatever like some people said on Github, 
i just created an Ingress to be able to point my subdomain to a different service and at first my Ingress had no IP address(it was empty).

```
NAME      HOSTS                            ADDRESS   PORTS   AGE
ingress   delivereo.tk,back.delivereo.tk             80      39s
```

I think it was because my 2 services for front-end app and back-end api had the Type of LoadBalancer.
I changed it to NodePort because they don't need external ip now that the ingress controller will manage what url goes where.

And when i did change the type of my services to NodePort, after 2 or 3 minutes the IP address of the Ingress appeared.
When i pointed my Cloudflare DNS to the new Ingress IP, i tested my subdomain and it worked !

BEFORE

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: delivereotk
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 80
  selector:
    app: delivereotk
  type: LoadBalancer
```

AFTER

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: delivereotk
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 80
  selector:
    app: delivereotk
  type: NodePort
```

Ingress

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - host: delivereo.tk
    http:
      paths:
        - backend:
            serviceName: delivereotk
            servicePort: 80
  - host: back.delivereo.tk
    http:
      paths:
        - backend:
            serviceName: backdelivereotk
            servicePort: 80
```

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same problem on GKE (Google Kubernetes Engine). It turned out there was a problem with ingress settings, I used incorrect names for desired services. You should check for errors by executing this command:

```
kubectl describe ingress <your-ingress-name>
```

Answer (score 2):

I faced similar issue, realized I needed to :

1. Enable the NGINX Ingress controller, run the following command:

   ```
   minikube addons enable ingress
   ```
2. Verify that the NGINX Ingress controller is running

   ```
   kubectl get pods -n kube-system
   ```

Expect nginx-ingress-controller pod in running status.

Comment: this question is not about minikube

Answer (score 2):

Ran into the exact same issue, and lost some time trying to understand.

After tailing my nginx-controller logs, the error was quite obvious :

```
W0612 21:00:52.496281       7 controller.go:240] ignoring ingress my-ing-my-ns-ing in my-ns based on annotation : ingress does not contain a valid IngressClass
I0612 21:00:52.496311       7 main.go:100] "successfully validated configuration, accepting" ingress="my-ns/my-ing"
I0612 21:00:52.518778       7 store.go:423] "Ignoring ingress because of error while validating ingress class" ingress="my-ns/my-ing" error="ingress does not contain a valid IngressClass"
```

And indeed, after describing my ingress resource, my annotations weren't there!

So after adding (among others) the following label to my ingress resource:
`kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx`

It's all good :) My Ingress resource is recognized by nginx ingress-controller, and taken care of.

PS: if you're using helm subcharts (for example for a generic micro service helm chart) don't forget to helm dependency upgrade before you redeploy ^^", could have saved some time with this one

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is a way to test your ingress resource.

You can do this by:

1. Look for the ip address of the ingress controller pod/s and use port 80/443 along with this ip.
2. Look for the service which is exposing the ingress controller deployment
3. If there is no service you can create one and expose the ingress controller deployment
4. If you want a hostname then you will need to manage the dns entries.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was simply a missing secret in the relevant namespace.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, for api version 1.20+, the only supported `pathType` value is `ImplementationSpecific`.

For details, check this link https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/http-balancer

Answer (score 1):

If TLS is part of your ingress, then missing secret can be the case.
To find the secret name, first describe your ingress:

```
kubectl describe ing <ing-name> -n <namespace>
```

Or find 'secretName' in your yaml file:

```
tls:
    - hosts:
        - example.com
      secretName: secret-name
```

And make sure that the secret is available when you list your secrets:

```
kubectl get secrets -n <namespace>
```

Answer (score 1):

first run - minikube addons enable ingress
Then run - minikube tunnel

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help on how to format code. The prose does not need to be bold either, it makes your post stand out to the wrong kind of attention. Also please consider explaining your code.

Answer (score 1):

For me this issue was happening because ingress controller was not running in my cluster. So I had to manually install and run the below command to install ingress controller.

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/controller-v0.48.1/deploy/static/provider/baremetal/deploy.yaml
```

Once this is done check if ingress controller pod is up it will be present in `ingress-nginx` namespace.

`kubectl get pods -n ingress-nginx`

```
NAME                                        READY   STATUS      RESTARTS   AGE
ingress-nginx-admission-create-xv8nh        0/1     Completed   0          2m2s
ingress-nginx-admission-patch-6gn6s         0/1     Completed   0          2m1s
ingress-nginx-controller-5cb8d9c6dd-lml8w   1/1     Running     0          2m3s
```

Once this was done the ingress address had appeared. It takes around 2-3 minutes.

Reference : [Install Ingress Controller](https://docs.k0sproject.io/v1.22.1+k0s.1/examples/nginx-ingress/)

Answer (score 1):

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/main/deploy/static/provider/cloud/deploy.yaml
```

```
kubectl get pods -n ingress-nginx
```

Comment: kubectl get pods -n ingress-nginx
run first this command if you get anything  even after running this command

kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/main/deploy/static/provider/cloud/deploy.yaml

after run once again this first command and apply once again in your ingress

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar case. The ingress we have written is just a ingress rule. To make the address available we need to have ingress controller pods running too.

Simply check if the controller pods is running or not

```
kubectl get pods
```

You should have the controller pods running as show in the image. If not you can install it using helm.

[image]

if you are using helm2 simply use the following command:

```
helm install stable/nginx-ingress --name my-nginx
```

follow this docs for different ways to install it. https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/

When doing helm install you might get the following issue if you don't have tiller installed.

```
Error: could not find tiller
```

**To fix it install tiller as following:**

```
kubectl -n kube-system create serviceaccount tiller
kubectl create clusterrolebinding tiller --clusterrole cluster-admin --serviceaccount=kube-system:tiller
helm init --service-account tiller
```

**To verify tiller is working:**

```
kubectl get pods --namespace kube-system
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same prob, and In my case, the cluster was configured with an `nginx` Ingress controller, where as my `Ingress.yaml`(see below) was referencing `nsx`.

```yaml
apiVersion: ...
kind: Ingress
metadata:
    name: example-ingress
    annotations:
        kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nsx <- should have been nginx
    ...
...
```

**My Learning:** Always check with the Kubernetes admin for the configuration, instead of spending hours (~8 hrs in my case) trying to debug xD

Answer (score 0):

In a cluster you need to have installed a LoadBalencer like metallb.

If you follow all the steps described in this post, you can create ingress object with an address from the metallb loadballancer, https://itnext.io/kubernetes-loadbalancer-service-for-on-premises-6b7f75187be8

Please find below how an ingress object looks like after followed all steps above

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
      {"apiVersion":"networking.k8s.io/v1","kind":"Ingress","metadata":{"annotations":{},"creationTimestamp":"2024-01-19T08:58:11Z","generation":1,"name":"hello-world-ingress","namespace":"default","resourceVersion":"8249","uid":"e3797acf-779f-44dd-ab28-4f9a977ff0b8"},"spec":{"ingressClassName":"nginx","rules":[{"host":"hello-world.exposed","http":{"paths":[{"backend":{"service":{"name":"web","port":{"number":3000}}},"path":"/","pathType":"Prefix"}]}}]},"status":{"loadBalancer":{}}}
  creationTimestamp: "2024-01-19T21:21:50Z"
  generation: 1
  name: hello-world-ingress
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "96582"
  uid: e20d676b-46a6-407d-9835-dabce6848e3c
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: hello-world.exposed
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: web
            port:
              number: 3000
        path: /
        pathType: Prefix
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
    - ip: 192.168.74.96
```

As result

```
$ kubectl get ingress
NAME                  CLASS   HOSTS                 ADDRESS         PORTS   AGE
hello-world-ingress   nginx   hello-world.exposed   192.168.74.96   80      65m
```